# Filter category ajax in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to make a custom category filter with ajax on frontpage.When I click on any of the custom taxonomy the content dissapears and I don't get any content.Custom post type are **aranzman**.

This is the **page-usluge.php**

```
 <ul class="categories-filters"> 
 <?php $args= array( 
'show_option_all' => 'All posts', //Text for button All 
'title_li' => __(''), 
'taxonomy' => 'vrsta-aranzmana', 
'post_type' => 'aranzman' ); 

wp_list_categories( $args ); ?> </ul> 

<?php $query = new WP_query ( $args ); 

if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?> 

<div id="main-content" class="row"> 
<div id="inside"> 
<div class="container"> 
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?> 
<article>
<a class="xiong-articlebox" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> 
<header> 
<h3><?php the_title( );?></h3> <p><em><?php the_date( 'j.n.Y'); ?> </em></p> </header> 
<p><?php the_excerpt();?></p> </a> </article> 
<?php endwhile; }?> 
</div><!-- container--> 
</div><!--inside --> 
</div> <!--row -->
```

This is the **ajax.js**

```
jQuery(function(){ 
var mainContent = jQuery('#main-content'), 
cat_links = jQuery('ul.categories-filters li a'); 

cat_links.on('click', function(e){ 
 e.preventDefault(); 
 el = jQuery(this); 
 var value = el.attr("href"); 
 mainContent.animate({opacity:"0.5"});
 mainContent.load(value + " #inside", function(){
 mainContent.animate({opacity:"1"}); 
  }); 
 }); 
});
```

And this is the **functions.php** calling the ajax.js

```
function ajax_theme_scripts() {

 //Ajax filter scripts     
 wp_register_script( 'ajax',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_theme_scripts' );
```

The 'not' working demo or example is on this link

[DEMO](https://demo5.webmedia.ba/usluge/)

Comment: You say you are doing an ajax call. But In your JS I don't see you doing an ajax call. This it the main article to help you get started with [WordPress ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I use this code from some tutorial video and he says ajax, however I don't know ajax and I was thinking too this is not ajax when I watch the video.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Wordpress already comes with an ajax handler (admin-ajax.php).

Here is the link to documentation for that: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins.

Briefly, what you have to do is:

1) add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_{your_action_id}', callback)

*Your call back here is supposed to be the filter function*

2) Write a javascrip ajax:
$.ajax({
    method: "expected method(POST)",
    url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php *(should be called dynamically with **wp_localize_script** => https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)*"
    dataType: "expected dataType(JSON)",
    data: {
        action: {your_action_id},
        "other data that you want to send"
    }
    success: function(response){}
});

To be able to handle the content of the response, you need to send as part of your response the html/text of the result. In this way, all you need to do is to use the simple jquery method $(selector).html(htmlOfResult);

To send data to your javascript success callback, you can use wp_send_json() https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json.

Comment: I'm new to ajax and its kinda hard stuff, I can't do it on this way on load? Thank you on this links for learning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is for ajax.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('ul.categories-filters li a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: Object_var.ajax_url_attr,
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            action: "myfilter_action",
            // I think you are using the href to check filter
            filter_req: $(this).attr('href')
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if(typeof response != "undefined")
                $('#inside .container').html(response.html_text);
        }
    });
});
});
```

here is for the function.php

```
<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
// Register first the ajax.js script
wp_enqueue_script('handle_of_script', 'link/to/ajax.js');

// Now send variable to the script
wp_localize_script('handle_of_script', "Object_var", [
    "ajax_url_attr" => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
]);
});

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter_action", function(){
$filter_req = $_POST['filter_req'];

// Run filter of whatever
$query_result = your_filter();

// Convert values to html/text
$html_text = convert_to_html_text($query_result);

// Send data to jQuery AJAX
wp_send_json(
    "html_text" => $html_text
);

wp_exit();
});

function convert_to_html_text($query) {
$html = "";

ob_start();
    // Maybe check if query is valid or have post ...
?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?> 
        <article>
            <a class="xiong-articlebox" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 
                <header> 
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <p>
                        <em><?php the_date( 'j.n.Y'); ?></em>
                    </p>
                </header> 
                <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
            </a>
        </article> 
    <?php endwhile;?>
<?
$html_text = ob_get_contents();

return $html;
}
```

I think this could help!

Comment: wp_send_json(
    "html_text" => $html_text
); It says error unexpected Double arrow

Comment: Sorry, I missed that! wp_send_json expect array as a parameter. So then, it should be wp_send_json( [ "html_text" => $html_text ] ).